# FreeSync Monitor - blurred screen

Tags: display

I have a problem with my FreeSync monitor. It basically works fine. But when I start the computer and start a game, or sometimes when I tab out of a game and return to it, the screen is extremely blurred when I move the camera or scroll. I noteced that it also happens inside of Microsofts Xbox App. On the desktop or inside a browser I can not see any blur.

I can fix that by deactivating FreeSync on my monitor (via the OSD of the monitor itself) and activate it again. That fixes it, until I tab out of the game (sometimes, not always) but it is very annyoing to always reactivate it, especially because some games don't react well to it or change the resolution after it. I have those problems since I got it.

I have the newest drivers installed, currently 451.67

When I got the monitor I followed this setup: [Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/ag6a9f/how_to_enable_adaptivesync_freesync_if_you_have/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

My specs:
Windows 10 Pro

CPU: Ryzen 7 3700X

GPU: Asus GTX 1070TI

MoBo: Asus ROG STRIX B450-F Gaming

Monitor: LG 34UC79G-B, 21:9, 144Hz, 2560x1080

The settings on my monitor are:
Game Mode: Custom Game (other modes are FPS1, FPS2 and RTS. I don't really know what these do, but all other modes too dark for my taste)
Black Stabilizer: 100
FreeSync: On
1ms Motion Blur Reduction: Off (can't be activated with FreeSync)
Response Time: Fast

The monitor is connected via a DisplayPort Cable (direct, no adapters, the one shipped with the monitor)

I have a second monitor conntected via HDMI that is not FreeSync (or any Sync) capable.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot? Have you tried new cables, have you disabled the secondary monitor,etc?

Comment: It also happens without the second monitor and other cables. I've reinstalled the drivers for the monitor, updated my GPU drivers, tried different settings on the monitor, I redid the setup in the NVidia Control Panel. I don't know what else to do...

Comment: Have you read any user reviews that might indicate others have had the same issue? It might be worth exchanging if nothing has worked